# transfer files between two node.js servers over http

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have two node.js/express servers that communicate with each other with http. **server A** is also communicates with the browser and can handle file upload requests. When file is uploaded to **server A** i want to transfer it as is to **server B** for further processing. what is the best way to do so? preferably with [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) module which is what i'm using for communication between the two servers.

This is what i got so far, but i am unable to transfer the file between the servers, the file is uploaded successfully to **server A**, and there is no Error while sending it to `server B`, but server B is doesn't recognise the request as file. what am i missing here?

**Server A Routes:**

```
'use strict';

// Routes

 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();
 const multer = require('multer');
 const upload = multer();

 const uploadController = require('./controllers/file/upload');

 router.post('/upload',upload.single('file'),uploadController); 

 module.exports = router;
```

**Server A uploadController:**

```
'use strict';

const RP = require('request-promise');

module.exports = (req, res) => {

  const body = req.body;

  if(req.file) {

    const file = req.file;

    RP('http://serverB.net/process', { 
      method: 'POST',
      formData: {file_buffer: file.buffer},
      body: body
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return res.status(200).send(response);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      return res.status(500).send(e.message);
    })
  }
  else {
     return res.status(500).send('unable to upload file');
  }
};
```

**Server B Routes:**

```
'use strict';

// Routes

 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();
 const multer = require('multer');
 const process = multer();

 const processFile = require('./controllers/file/processFile');

 router.post('/process', process.single('file'), processFile); 

 module.exports = router;
```

**Server B processFile:**

here i want to process the file from **Server A** but `req.file` is `undefined`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (req, res) => {

  if(req.file) {
  // here i want to do something with the file.
  }

};
```

Comment: Try this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279922/file-data-transfer-between-two-node-js-servers

Comment: @kasey That deals with communication over **WebSockets**.  This question deals with two servers communicating over **http**.

Comment: Have you found an ideal solution?  I am attempting the same thing but having trouble sending the file.  Using [form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data) with [request](https://github.com/request/request)

Answer (score 1):

`router.post('/process', process.single('file'), processFile);`

This line, specifically `process.single('file')` tells multer to look for a field `file` which will contain the actual file data. However, in your request you never specify a value for `file`. Change the name `file_buffer` to just `file` in your request. Or change your `process.single()` to `process.single('file_buffer')`

```
RP('http://serverB.net/process', { 
  method: 'POST',
  formData: {
    file: file.buffer,
    body: body
  }
})
.then((response) => {
  return res.status(200).send(response);
})
.catch((e) => {
  return res.status(500).send(e.message);
})
```

Now on Server B, inside `processFile` you should see a `req.body` with a field `body` that contains your entire body passed in your request and you should have a `req.file` now that contains your multer file object.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding that you are using so send the file may not be `multipart/form-data`.  Try setting that header in your file send request.  Express `req.files` will only be populated with a `multipart/form-data` [Express `req.files` will only be populated with a `multipart/form-data`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.properties) .  You're already using **multer** so I'm guessing the sending encoding is not quite right.

```
RP({
    method: "POST",
    uri: "serverB.net",
    form: {
        file: file.buffer
    },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
});
```