# Sending files between HTTP endpoints nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Working on a file transfer utility and having a mess of a time getting the transfers done correctly.

I have folder watching done with Chokidar, and on add in Chokidar, I create a file object added to an array. Each object looks like this:

```
l.files.push({
  dateAdded: Date.now(),
  fileName: fileName,
  filePath: filePath,
  fullPath: p
  });
```

and the client checks in, get's the number of files available for download, then makes an HTTP Request for each of the files:(enclosed in object)

```
getFile: (loc, home) => {
  var connection = home + 'files/?loc=' + loc;
  h.get(connection, (res) =>{
    let filePath = config.thisIncoming;
    console.dir(res.body); 
  });   
}
```

`home` is the baseUrl for the api call, `loc` is a location identifier for the API to find.

The Express endpoint is setup to respond to the call like this:

```
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
  // console.dir(req);
  for( let f of filePaths){
    console.dir(f);
    if((f.name === req.query.loc)&&(f.files.length > 0)){
      let file = f.files.pop();
      var fileName = file.fileName;
      fs.readFile(file.fullPath, (err, dat) => {
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.send({status: 'NO FILES'});
        }else{
         if(dat){
            console.log(dat);
            res.send({name: fileName, data: dat});
          }
        }
      });
      }
    }
});
```

I didn't want to go the `res.download()` or `res.sendFile()` methods as I wanted to be able to send the file name along with the data in the file. I've set it up to send a buffer, but on the client side, it logs `undefined` to the console where it should log the buffer data.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a library that can help with this? What would be a proper/better way to do this?

Comment: First off, `res.send()` accepts a string only so you can't send a javascript object with that.  You could send JSON with `res.json()`, but that does not handle binary data if your file data is not a string itself.  Though I don't know the details myself, I suspect the proper way to do this is by formatting a response as  MIME part where you can specify the filename in the MIME headers and then use an appropriate MIME encoding for the file.

Comment: Been looking at this answer, and I like the idea of using streams and sockets to handle this over Http, and I think I almost have it.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335686/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-sending-files-between-nodejs-servers